# Bean (sometimes) not being populated in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet that handles request in th `doGet()` method which looks like

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    String msg = req.getParameter("message");
    String msisdn = req.getParameter("number");
    logger.info("incoming message " + message);
    Alert alert = extractElements(message, number);
    saveToDb(alert);
}
```

I basically need to extract the elements of the message and save to db.

Sometimes however the alert bean isn't populated with data.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sometimes however the alert bean isn't populated with data.

It seems sometime your request contains null param for message and/or number.

1. are you sure each time you are invoking `GET` request to this servlet?
2. are you sure each time your request contains data , I meant is there any interceptor which filters it out check for that.

**A Suggestion**

and for better `MVC` design  your servlet should only act as controller , there should be another layer for performing service related operations.

Comment: tks for prompt responce. The url is the same in all cases and contain th same data.

Comment: can you post a bit of code how do you make GET request to this servlet

Comment: also you are not passing data from request to extractElements `Alert alert = extractElements(message, number);`

Comment: Sorted. tks for pointing me in th right direction.  I now store the alert in the request and access it from there in all methods.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this:

```
Alert alert = extractElements(message, number);
```

probably supposed to be:

```
Alert alert = extractElements(msg , msisdn );
```

Comment: Thanks for the observation. It was typed wrongly in SO but it was ok in eclipse.